# Findings issues with sed in bash script

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I am trying to delete a line from xml file by comparing resource name tab value from same xml file, the below bash script works if I put logfilename as Mansing but gets failed when I keep the value as 'jdbc/test'. Any help?

bash code:

```
logfilename="jdbc/test"

sed -i "/\<$logfilename\>/d" /home/test/test.xml
```

`test.xml` file is as below:

```
<a>
<Resource name="jdbc/test" auth="container" url="localhost:8080"
<Resource name="Mansing" auth="container" url="localhost:8080"
</a>
```

Comment: See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jdbc/test` contains `/` that is interpreted as a delimiter by the sed command. Try to escape it:

```
logfilename="jbdc\/test"
```

or change the default delimiter in your address by prefixing the first new delimiter with `\`:

```
sed -i "\~\<$logfilename\>~d" /home/test/test.xml
```

Comment: logfilename value will be provided by end user, I have put here as hardcoded.

Comment: See the edit for using another delimiter.

Comment: Great help. Thank you.